# Is there an automated way to tag Docker images inside Compose based on Git version?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I have a CI process (based on a compose file) that builds the docker images every night.

I'd like the image to get a TAG based on GIT automatically.

I work with .env files, and I'd like to put a bash command there, say:

```sh
TAG=$(git rev-list --all --count).$(git rev-list HEAD --count)
```

and then in docker-compose.yml:

```
 web:
    image: docker-registry/myapp/web:${TAG}
    build:
      context: ./web
```

I know I can pass arguments e.g.:

```
TAG=$(git rev-list --all --count) docker build . -t web:$TAG
```

but I have about 10 images so I have to use a compose file.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem, looks like the only way is to generate compose file at the moment

Comment: FWIW : I think you would have a better time taking the hash of the head commit (e.g : `git rev-parse --short HEAD`) rather than the total number of commits in your own repo (which could stay the same after a number of actions such as `commit --amend`, `rebase`, etc ..., or change without your `HEAD` commit changing)